# How can I style the Google custom search box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a site search, I am using google custom search, but it has its own style. I want to change the style of the search box using CSS.

Please no AJAX & no jQuery.

JavaScript:

```
(function() {
    var cx = 'myID';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
```

HTML:

```
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

I want sth like : [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103263/google-custom-search-csev2-help-on-styling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DOM inspection tool right click on the search bar and inspect element . And you can determine the IDs and classes and the default styles .
Next, you can make your own css rules which will override the default ones try the css code like this :

```
input.gsc-input {}
input.gsc-search-button {}
form.gsc-search-box {}
div.gsc-control-cse {}
```

Comment: its not that simple google overrides the style after loading the page using javascript. its a bit tricky, he may apply style using javascript but after 1 or 2 seconds using `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Or set `!important` which in this situation, should be fine too

Comment: @B.Friedrichs I think !important should be fine